# Hide * in Data Grid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am working for the first time on data grid. I have dragged a data grid onto my windows form.
I want to hide the * (which is present before the first column) in the data grid. Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Comment: WPF or Winform? Post your code

Comment: It's a winform Thanks for your reply. I found the solution by setting rowheadervisible to fasle

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by setting rowheadervisible to fasle